# Code::Blocks MinGW Windows Defender Trojan:Win32/Fuery.C!cl

Tags: c, mingw, codeblocks

I'm testing a simple "hello world" program in Code::Blocks 20.03 and MinGW (GCC Build-20200227-1 9.2.0, installed separately), but I got no message on console when running it:

[image]

At first I thought it was a compiler issue due to that *"no target" in "no project"* message, but then I realized the problem was Windows Defender blocking the .exe file, saying the program contains: Trojan:Win32/Fuery.C!cl

In [this](https://github.com/itead/Sonoff_Devices_DIY_Tools/issues/27) topic this issue was related before, but it seems it is happening again.

I've manually allowed the .exe file on my Windows Defender, and sent it to virustotal, which indeed pointed the threat from 29 engines:

https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/2d21be5d87055eea18016112c1779e11a583ce5e3df47595aedf3fad4a8e12f6/detection

Is it a known issue? What is the recomended action to solve this?

Comment: You could try several things: 1. Install the compiler separately, e.g. from MSYS2 (CB ships with a stone-age compiler, so it's worth updating anyway). 2. Install CB on a different machine, in case yours is infected and alters the .exe.

Comment: My MinGW was installed separatelly. If my computer was infected, the same Windows Defender wouldn't point the threat? But I'll try it on another machine anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Where did you get your MinGW?

Comment: I got MinGW from mingw.org->downloads, which took me to osdn.net/projects/mingw/releases. Than I downloaded that "mingw-get-setup.exe" for Windows.

Comment: I have downloaded from the same exact source and am having the same issue - have you found a solution? I also checked virustotal and found roughly the same amount of engines flagging it.

Comment: Having the same problem here.... lol https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62622758/c-programs-getting-detected-as-malware

Comment: I've been having the same issue. It's quite odd that Windows Defender is causing this issue... It would make sense that this is a recent problem, and is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

If you check virus total it's listed as a different name each time. It's just a false positive. I had the same problem and after enabling it in windows defender it ran fine in Atom/VsCode