# Behavior/Win32/Execution

Tags: c++, virus, windows-defender

Guys i have a c++ exe that is the sources

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    char* appdata = std::getenv("APPDATA");
    if(appdata) {
        std::cout << "Appdata: " << appdata << '\n';
        std::string cmd = std::string("schtasks /create /tn System64 /tr \"") +
                          appdata +
                          "\\Honeygain\\Honeygain.exe\" /sc ONLOGON";

        system(cmd.c_str());
    }
}
```

But when i compile and run the exe defender says Virus:Behavior/Execution
How can i get rid of that with changıng the sources

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62364507/2129218

Comment: @BuildSucceeded I believe this is different from question linked by you. Defender detects this because untrusted program is calling out to an already trusted Windows administrative command. Which is not false positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct because your program is doing something potentially dangerous/unwanted (creating a scheduled task) on behalf of user who executed it. Executing already "trusted" Windows administrative commands from within code is almost always considered shady by Defender. Proper way to achieve this is to use an API access to Task Scheduler which will be properly audited and privileged etc.

To create scheduled tasks there is a `ITaskService` COM interface. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/weekly-trigger-example--c---) is an official tutorial how to use it.