# C programs getting detected as Malware

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, exe, malware

Recently my C programs started to act weirdly and I had no idea why... Then I realized that they were being flagged by my antivirus program as malware... First I thought there's a malware in my compiler (I'm using CodeBlocks IDE with MinGW-GCC as c compiler), Antivirus scan returned nothing.

So I started experimenting on it...

I wrote a simple hello world using c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

Soon as I compiled it windows defender flagged it as **Trojan:Win32/Fuerboos.C!cl**  : Threat level **Severe**

So I uploaded the exe to VirusTotal
[VirusTotal results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6NJT.png)

30 engines flagged the file as malware...

Also gmail doesn't allow you to attach it as an executable file...

Is anyone experiencing this? Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: Where did you get your compiler?

Comment: Does gmail allow you to attach *any* executable file?

Comment: What is the size of your compiled file for your hello example?

Comment: @Hoppo 40kbytes... normal size

Comment: FWIW I just submitted the Hello World executable (using `puts`) to VirusTotal and three didn't like it: SecureAge APEX (malicious), Bkav (malware), Cylance (unsafe).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat official site...

Comment: @WeatherVane this is crazy -,-

Comment: @SupulEdirisinghe Can you give a link? There's MinGW, MinGW-w64, and at least the latter has several different distributions.

Comment: My compiled binary using gcc is 8k.Uploaded to Virus Total with zero flags.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i downloaded it from mingw.org https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/releases/

Comment: @Hoppo now that's weird....

Comment: compiling your program on PI4 raspbian gcc 8.3.6 : *No engines detected this file*

Comment: @bruno virus engines only detect exe files... it doesn't catch .o files or anything

Comment: @SupulEdirisinghe I did on the executable of course

Answer (score -3):

It could be you are really having a malware or it is a security risk as mentioned here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string . Try using `puts` to see if you still have the issue

Comment: Your link says *"use of unchecked user input as the format string parameter"*. OP's format string is hardcoded rather than inputted.